# Как вывести объекты из класса List

Tags: c#, list, json.net

Имею json такого вида (категории товаров) =

```
part_types: {
29662101: "Щетка стеклоочистителя",
29834101: "Молдинг лобового стекла",
30177101: "Стекло заднее",
43326101: "Стекло лобовое",
43334101: "Стекло форточки",
43335101: "Стекло боковое опускное",
43336101: "Стекло кузова боковое (не опускное)"
}
```

Десериализую через Json.Net, указывая при этом что класс у нас динамический (`dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Out)`)

Как вывести все категории товаров, при том что я заранее не знаю какие объекты мне нужны?

Не знаю что вставить туда:

```
foreach (dynamic item in data.part_types)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item.НЕ ЗНАЮ ЧТО СЮДА ВСТАВИТЬ);
}
```

P/S Надеюсь будет понятно :)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, что вам нужно, сработает вот что. Реальный тип вашего `item` — `JProperty` (не забудьте `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`). Поэтому должно покатить такое:

```
foreach (JProperty item in data.part_types)
{
    string value = (string)item.Value;
    // у вас есть значение, делайте с ним, что хотите
}
```

Comment: что такое `p` у вас?

Comment: @Андрей: Тьфу, опечатка, это `item`, конечно.